# Using ActiveMQ in a React application

Tags: reactjs, activemq-classic

I am creating a web app. The server is implemented with .NET Core and will send messages using `ActiveMQ`. My problem is how to use ActiveMQ with the CLIENTS which are implemented using React.

I found examples using ActiveMQ with JavaScript here:  http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html

They say you should define ActiveMQ like this:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, I'm not sure how to integrate it with React.. With React, I'm used to installing an NPM package whenever I need some additional functionality. How do I get to the point where I can use the API like shown in the examples in the link above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use a standard protocol like AMQP or STOMP and use a client implementation which is already in NPM:

- [AMQP 1.0 client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp10)
- [STOMP.js client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompjs)

Comment: Didn't think of searching a package for a protocol.. but isn't it a bit lacking without the api of the broker itself?

Comment: Your question says you want to "send messages." Both AMQP and STOMP are perfectly adequate messaging protocols for most use-cases, including yours. What other, broker-specific API do you need?

Comment: I want to take advantage of topics and have the message broker send push messages to the clients whenever the server adds a message to the topic in the message broker

Comment: Both AMQP and STOMP support the semantics you're looking for. I recommend you do some research on them.

Comment: I posted an answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082513/using-a-message-broker-with-end-user-clients-directly). However, that doesn't impact whether or not this answer is correct. Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as such to help other users who may have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify why. Thanks!

Comment: If you could add some simple examples how to send and receive message inside a react app using these protocols, I'll accept the answer

Comment: I'm not an expert on the linked client implementations. The documentation for each of those has examples you can adapt for use in your application.